# Display error message instead of 'no rows selected'

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I want my function to display 'Empty Invoice Found!' Or 'Invoice Not Found' error messages.
But when I select the data with error(doesnt exist in the table), it return 'no rows selected'. Please guide me with the correct way to SELECT.

```
SET ECHO ON;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalInvoiceAmount(InvoiceNo IN       INVOICE_ITEM.InvoiceNumber%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
TotalCost NUMBER(20);

CURSOR X_RECORD IS SELECT * FROM INVOICE_ITEM;
CURSOR Y_RECORD IS SELECT * FROM INVOICE_ITEM;

tempCost NUMBER:=0;
InvoiceCheck BOOLEAN:=FALSE;
InvoiceEmpty BOOLEAN:=TRUE;

BEGIN
FOR Record IN X_RECORD LOOP 
    IF Record.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNo THEN
        InvoiceCheck:=TRUE;
        EXIT;
    ELSE
        InvoiceCheck:=FALSE;
    END IF;
END LOOP;   

FOR Record IN Y_RECORD LOOP 
    IF Record.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNo AND InvoiceCheck=FALSE THEN
        InvoiceEmpty:=TRUE;
        EXIT;
    ELSE
        InvoiceEmpty:=FALSE;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

IF InvoiceCheck=FALSE AND InvoiceEmpty=FALSE THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invoice Not Found!');
    RETURN -1;
ELSIF InvoiceCheck=FALSE AND InvoiceEmpty=TRUE THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Empty Invoice Found!');
    RETURN 0;
ELSE
    FOR Record IN X_RECORD LOOP 
        IF Record.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNo THEN
            tempCost:=tempCost+(Record.UnitPrice*Record.Quantity);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    TotalCost:=tempCost;
    RETURN TotalCost;
END IF;
END;
```

/

```
SELECT invoicenumber,totalInvoiceAmount(invoicenumber) AS "Total Cost" FROM INVOICE_ITEM Where invoicenumber=2011011;

SELECT invoicenumber,totalInvoiceAmount(invoicenumber) AS "Total Cost" FROM INVOICE_ITEM where invoicenumber=2011010;
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  What line is throwing the error?  Writing a function like this seems very inefficient. You are already doing a select on the INVOICE_ITEM table, so you have the data at-hand.  What is the purpose of the function.  ALso, your cursor is selecting all rows from the table, then filtering them?  I don't think you even need this, just use an aggregate function (SUM) to do the same thing.  There are definite uses for PL/SQL, but it can be a crutch to avoid learning how to do the same thing in straight SQL, which will be faster.

Comment: Both of the cursors read from the same table; thus, if the first cursor doesn't find data matching the input invoice number, the second  will also not find data which matches the input invoice number. I suspect your logic is not correct and that other fields or tables should be involved. Is there an INVOICE table which the first cursor should be reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages you want come from a function which you are calling in a SELECT statement.  So if that SELECT returns no rows there are are no rows which can be used to call that function.

I'm afraid it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but whatever it is you need a different approach.  Having said which I suggest something like this might be give you what you want (in a more orthodox and more efficient fashion):

```
SELECT invoicenumber, 
       sum(UnitPrice*Quantity) AS "Total Cost" 
FROM INVOICE_ITEM 
where invoicenumber=2011010
group by InvoiceNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ECHO ON;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalInvoiceAmount(InvoiceNo IN       INVOICE_ITEM.InvoiceNumber%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
TotalCost NUMBER(20);
invoice_not_found EXCEPTION ;
empty_invoice_found EXCEPTION ;


CURSOR X_RECORD IS SELECT * FROM INVOICE_ITEM;
CURSOR Y_RECORD IS SELECT * FROM INVOICE_ITEM;

tempCost NUMBER:=0;
InvoiceCheck BOOLEAN:=FALSE;
InvoiceEmpty BOOLEAN:=TRUE;

BEGIN
FOR Record IN X_RECORD LOOP 
    IF Record.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNo THEN
        InvoiceCheck:=TRUE;
        EXIT;
    ELSE
        InvoiceCheck:=FALSE;
    END IF;
END LOOP;   

FOR Record IN Y_RECORD LOOP 
    IF Record.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNo AND InvoiceCheck=FALSE THEN
        InvoiceEmpty:=TRUE;
        EXIT;
    ELSE
        InvoiceEmpty:=FALSE;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

IF InvoiceCheck=FALSE AND InvoiceEmpty=FALSE THEN
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invoice Not Found!');
    RAISE invoice_not_found;
    --RETURN -1;
ELSIF InvoiceCheck=FALSE AND InvoiceEmpty=TRUE THEN
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Empty Invoice Found!');
    RAISE empty_invoice_found
    RETURN 0;
ELSE
    FOR Record IN X_RECORD LOOP 
        IF Record.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNo THEN
            tempCost:=tempCost+(Record.UnitPrice*Record.Quantity);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    TotalCost:=tempCost;
    RETURN TotalCost;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
when invoice_not_found then
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invoice Not Found!');
 raise -1;
when empty_invoice_found then
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Empty Invoice Found!');
 raise 0;

END;
```

You can catch it in an exception and handle it accordingly , let me know if it works